# How to bulk create records

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an application in which the user has to answer 50 questions. 
These questions I receive via a web-service and the releated answers are as well in the webservice. I assign these quesition to a ticket number. 
Each 50 questions and the releated answers belong to one ticket.

My problem is to display ans save the choices of the end-user. What is the best-practice here.

I use typescript and angular.

My current approach is:

Create a table with the 50 records and a dropdown list in each row to answer the question. So I prefetch the questions and show the dropdown list.

My issue is that I do not know how to access each individual line of the 50 records to identify if they have answered and saved.

I would like to save them all at once (if all are answered) or save them one by one (which is not the preferred solution as it might not be an autonomous transaction? ).

I tried this by using formGroup for the table. But this was not successful.

Maybe the table is a complete wrong approach?

Any help is appreciated!
Augeres

Comment: You might want to use `formArray`

Answer (score 0):

This question has a lot to do with user experience and the requirements of your project.

From the point of view of the user, if you need to answer 50 questions and click on a dropdown for each one and wait for the related answers to be fetched and painted below the question is a bit painful. The best approach here would be to fetch all the questions with the related answers from the web service (all in one http call) and only paint them in a table or any other element.

But if the user would only asks a few of the answers, your approach is right. You can do it very easily in Angular with [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray). I would do it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions">
  <button (click)="questionsUnfoldedMap[question.id]">Fold/Unfold</button>
  <p>{{ question.title }}</p>
  <app-related-questions *ngIf="isQuestionUnfolded()" 
                         [relatedAnswers]="relatedAnswersMap[question.id]"
                         (questionAnswered)="onQuestionAnswered(question.id, $event)">
  </app-related-questions>
</div>
```

Let's explain the code. You will need to mantain a map (just a javascript object) to know which questions are folded or unfolded (the key would be the question id and the value would be just a boolean (`questionsUnfoldedMap` in the html above). Each time you unfold a question, you need to fetch the data from the web service and store it in another map (`relatedAnswersMap`, that is passed to the `RelatedQuestionsComponent`) which stores the answers for each question. Every time the user answer a question, the `onQuestionAnswered(questionId, $event)` from the nested component would be fired. All you have to do in this method is just store the answer id for the question id in the form array and just send it to the server when the user submits the form.

Finally, I don't know how you need to send your data to the web service, but in this case I would suggest you to send all the data in a single http call, because if the user answers all of the questions you would need to make 50 calls to the web service...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer.
I think it is the best to show all 50 questions at once. And there are arround 2-5 answers... within a dropdown list.

What I did now is the following in html:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-8">
        <form name="editForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit()" #editForm="ngForm">
            <h2 id="jhi--entry-heading">Create or edit a  Entry Test</h2>
            <div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="Questions">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr jhiSort [(predicate)]="predicate" [(ascending)]="reverse" [callback]="reset.bind(this)">
                            <th jhiSortBy="id"><span>ID</span>
                                <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
                            </th>
                            <th jhiSortBy="name"><span>Question</span>
                                <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody infinite-scroll (scrolled)="loadPage(page + 1)" [infiniteScrollDisabled]="page >= links['last']" [infiniteScrollDistance]="0">
                            <tr *ngFor="let Question of Questions ;trackBy: trackId; let i = index;">
                            <th scope="row">{{Question.id}}</th>
                            <td>{{Question.name}} {{Question.description}}</br>
                                      <select class="form-control" id="answerid">
                                        <option disabled hidden [value]="selectUndefinedOptionValue">-- select --</option>
                                        <option *ngFor="let answer of Question.answers; let j = index;" [value]="answer.id">{{answer.description}}</option>
                                    </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" id="cancel-save" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="previousState()">
                            <fa-icon [icon]="'ban'"></fa-icon>&nbsp;<span>Cancel</span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" id="save-entity" [disabled]="editForm.form.invalid || isSaving" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <fa-icon [icon]="'save'"></fa-icon>&nbsp;<span>Save</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This table works fine it is prefilled from the service and you can select an item from the drop-down list. 
But now I'm completely lost how to access the individual records in the table from typescript. I want to access the selected answer + the related question. Can i receive the complete table as one object?

Thanks for your help!
augeres